# How could I implement a word skipping solution into my program?

Tags: c++, string, function

I would like a way for my program to ignore the following word: "the" "with" "on" when included in the user command.

Currently the program simply accepts two words as verb and noun strings for command.

```
string one = "the";
string two = "with";
string three = "on";
string four = "in";

int main()
{
    string noun = "";
    string verb = "";


    getline(cin, verb);
    int x = verb.find(' ');

    if (x > -1) {
        noun = verb.substr(verb.find(" ") + 1);
        verb = verb.substr(0, verb.find(" "));
    }

    if (verb == "living") {
        if (noun == "room") {
            Livingroom();
        }
    }
    else if (verb == "bed") {
        if (noun == "room") {
            Bedroom();
        }
    }


}
```

I expect the program to work normally even with the inclusion of the words mentioned earlier in the user commands.

Comment: Why not read the entire line into a `std::string` (say `std::string line;`) then create a `std::stringstream` (say `std::stringstring ss(line);`) from `line` and then loop `while (ss >> word) { ... }` and within the loop check against the words to exclude and ignore them if found? You are better served using a `std::vector<std::string>` to hold the words you want to exclude which will make them simple to check and ignore.

Comment: Put your exclusion words into a `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: @paddy, `std::set` is quite nice for that. Even shorter than a range-based loop over the `std::vector<std::string>` to match the exclusion words. [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sam, while it is unclear just exactly what your expected `noun/verb` order of input is, you can utilize one of the standard containers to hold your the words you want to exclude (as well as a list of special words that would swap the order).

You are already using `std::string`. While my first thought was a `std::vector<std::string>` for the exclusions @paddy makes a good suggestion that will simplify things further using an `std::unordered_set` (or `std::set`). The difference being the underlying data structure where `std::unordered_set` has slightly better constant time complexity than the sorted `std::set` (see [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) compared to [std::unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set).

Using a `std::unordered` set to exclude your unwanted words allows you to simply loop over the command input using `.find(word)` on the current word and a comparison to the `.end()` element of the unordered_set to determine whether `word` is in the exclusion set.

A short example could be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <unordered_set>

int main (void) {

    /* unordered set of words to exclude from the command */
    std::unordered_set<std::string> excl = { "in", "on", "the", "with" };
    std::string word;                       /* current word read from input */
    std::array<std::string, 2> command;     /* 2 string array (noun/verb) */
    size_t n = 0;                           /* simple counter */

    std::cout << "enter command: ";

    /* read words in command until the 1st two non-excluded words found */
    while (n < command.size() && std::cin >> word) {
        auto search = excl.find(word);      /* search for word in set */
        if (search == excl.end())           /* if word not excluded */
            command.at(n++) = word;         /* add to array, increment count */
    }

    /* output first two non-excluded words */
    std::cout << "\nnoun: " << command.at(0) << 
                "\nverb: " << command.at(1) << '\n';
}
```

(**note:** the implementation of special words, like `"living"` or `"bed"` in another set is left to you, as is whether to swap the order of noun/verb to meet your needs)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/set_noun_verb
enter command: in the bed in the room with the candlestick

noun: bed
verb: room
```

Look things over. There a many many ways to implement this, but after the suggestion of a `std::unordered_set`, that is probably one of the simplest way to exclude a set of words from consideration. You can also use your choice of container for the noun/verb `command` as well. A `std::array<std::string, 2>` made sense, but so would a `std::vector` or `std::pair` or any of the other containers you may ultimately decide to use.

Comment: The solution implemented using std::unordered_set worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.